# Callee RC: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED 0x80040154

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan, tmp

I have been running VirtualBox for a few months now and I recently updated El Capitan. After do so, the VirtualBox would no longer start. The error message that displayed was:

"Callee RC: NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED 0x80040154". Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I encountered this error:
"Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object. The application will now terminate. Callee RC: REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154)" I was able to fix it by restoring my VirtualBox.xml file from VirtualBox.xml-prev.
These are found in your .VirtualBox directory, for example: - `C:\Users\{username}\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` - `C:\Users\{username}\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml-prev`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

downloading the newest kernel compile it with your own .config, recompile VirtualBox and everything should work.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some web research, I was able to find the following solution. I had to change the permissions on the /tmp directory to 777 in order to get VirtualBox to start. Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box was not loading the VM, and I kept getting this error:

> 06/08/2017  MacBook Pro 2017 Sierra issue loading the vm virtual
>   machine
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component:  MachineWrap
>   Interface:  IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
>
> Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.Callee RC:
>   NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)

After poking around I found a solution:

1. open virtual box and right click on the virtual machine thats not working and select remove then select remove only! (stack overflow will not allow me to post more than 2 links or pictures so this picture is not available wtf?)
2. after removing the VM, navigate to machine and select add.
   [Screen shot of step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibVh1.jpg)
3. now a window should have popped up, navigate to the VM's you want and select open and everything should work as normal.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqMF.jpg)